# Change text background color when reading values from database

Tags: javascript, jquery

My HTML form reads the values from the database (using PHP) and display those values in the text inputs. The desired outcome is to change the color of the background of the text fields when displaying those values.

```
$(function() {
$('#table1 text').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == '1') {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#f4b4b4');
 }
  if ($(this).text() == '2') {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#c7f4b4');
 }
  if ($(this).text() == '3')  {
   $(this).css('background-color', '#f2cda6');
 }
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: With a bit more open context we can perfectly help you. But you ain't giving your issue nor a HTML context.

Comment: You should tag this as jQuery not javascript.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice, this time given the code from an answer to the previous?

Comment: why not just append the value to a class using your php?

Comment: The previous code works fine when the data is entered, but it is not changing the color automatically while reading the values from the database. With my limited knowledge of js it seems the problem is due to the  addEventListener function which is not working while reading values. may be I am wrong!

Comment: If you are going to persist with doing this with js, have a look at your selector - I doubt your html contains a text element but as you have not created a [mcve] I vote to close

Comment: Solved it. Thanks!